# jQuery validate with .post

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, validation

I am using the jQuery validate plug-in to validate a form and if it validates I would like to post the data.

Below is the code I have so far. How can I change code so that the post only happens if the form validates? Currently it posts the data regardless of whether it's valid or not...which is not what I want to happen.

```
$("#next_architect").live("click",function() {
    $("#architect_form").valid();
    $.post('scripts/register_user.php', 
        $("#architect_form").serializeArray(), function(data) {
            alert("inserted");
        }
    );
});
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to do:

```
if( $("#architect_form").valid() ) { /* post code */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to setup a success handler:

```
$(".selector").validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {
       // do other stuff for a valid form
    form.submit();
   }
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions